# Why do I get Hp printed instead of an empty line?

Tags: c++

I have a very simple question, why is the output of this code the way it is?

I am using Dev-C++ 5.11 with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    char Str[] = "abcdefg";
    ptr = Str;
    ptr += 8;
    cout << ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the code to print an empty line.

For some reason, there seems to be a space character at position 7, you can detect that by changing `ptr +=8;` to `ptr+=7;`.

but what is weirder to me is that there are 3 more characters that can't be displayed unless you jump beyond the array limit by 2, which in this case we add 8 to the pointer. the characters are: "H,(a weird filled square),p"

[screenshot of the output from my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzy7F.jpg)

Comment: That's called a buffer overrun, and the results will be undefined. The character at pos 7 is the terminating null character that marks the end of a character array when being used as a c style string.

Comment: but I have tried the same thing with larger arrays and it just shows what is expected an empty line!

Comment: As I said, the results are undefined.

Comment: thanks steve, at least I got the right name for the thing.

Comment: dont use dev-c++

Comment: In many computers, if `Str[8]` is a valid memory address, the program will print characters from that location and beyond until an error occurs, a terminating `'\0'` is found or a memory access failure occurs.  Memory access could be no memory or memory that your program is not allowed to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot expect the empty line when you try to access memory beyond your array.
At position 7 you have the `'\0'`.
`C` strings are terminated by this character and it is also used by the printing function to know when it should stop printing.

At position 8 you are beyond this character and the behavior of the program is undefined since the memory you are accessing might be everything.
The characters that you are able to print are just a representation of the memory beyond the string. They might change or exception might be thrown.

Character `'a'` is at position `0` and character `'g'` is at position `6` you should not access memory outside of this region except if you are trying to hack something.

Answer (score 4):

> I would expect the code to print an empty line.

That expectation is misguided. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> For some reason, there seems to be a space character at position 7

There is not. There is a null terminator at position 7.

> but what is weirder to me is that there are 3 more characters that can't be displayed unless you jump beyond the array limit by 2 ...

The behaviour of accessing an array outside of its bounds is undefined.